# I have overclocked to 4.7ghz, with core temps it reads at max load at 100 degrees C, is that too hot?

Tags: cpu, cooling, temperature, intel-core-i7, overclocking

I have a i7-3770k processor and I have over clocked it to 4.7ghz. When it runs at 100% load, core temp reads it at 100 degree's Celsius. I have it liquid cooled, but it don't know how much it is cooling it. Is 100 degrees at max load too hot for my processor? I also have fans and everything. Should I be concerned?

Comment: Well, Intel's [ARK for that processor](http://ark.intel.com/products/65523) lists a `T_CASE` value of 67.4°C...

Comment: If my CPU is over 80C, that's too hot in my opinion. Liquid Cooled CPU shouldn't be at those temps. Make sure that you did a leak test and that you do not have any air gaps. Make sure that the heatsink is mounted properly as well.

Answer (score 4):

Yes. Your overclocking failed and is making the CPU *slower* because it is throttling. Are you 100% sure your cooling block is properly mated to the CPU? Are you sure coolant is flowing? What's your max temperature at full load at factory clocking? (If you didn't measure that first, you are not overclocking properly.)

Answer (score 1):

The Ivy Bridge CPUs are getting very hot becasue of the pool thermal interface material used by Intel inside the CPU. Read this article to understand why:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ivy_Bridge_%28microarchitecture%29#Thermal_performance_and_heat_issues

Reduce the OC to avoid damage.